# How to order by specific column without breaking groups?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below and I want to order this table by date without breaking groups.

```
id    group       date
1 |   group1 | 2011-11-24
2 |   group2 | 2011-08-20
3 |   group1 | 2011-03-11
4 |   group3 | 2011-05-05
5 |   group3 | 2012-01-01
```

I only consider the latest updated group element when ordering by date.

I want to get order like;

```
id    group       date
5 |   group3 | 2012-01-01
4 |   group3 | 2011-05-05
1 |   group1 | 2011-11-24
3 |   group1 | 2011-03-11
2 |   group2 | 2011-08-20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added also another group wit the same dates, so that you see that you have also to define an order for the group to be displayed, in case the same dates.

To get your wanted order i  added in the CTE a sorting row, which is he max date for every Group

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     ("id" int, "group" varchar(6), "date" date)
> ;
> INSERT INTO table1
>     ("id", "group", "date")
> VALUES
>     (1, 'group1', '2011-11-24'),
>     (2, 'group2', '2011-08-20'),
>     (3, 'group1', '2011-03-11'),
>     (4, 'group3', '2011-05-05'),
>     (5, 'group3', '2012-01-01'),
>         (6, 'group4', '2011-05-05'),
>     (7, 'group4', '2012-01-01')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT
> "id", "group", "date"
> ,MAX("date") OVER (PARTITION BY "group") As maxdategroup
> FROM
> table1)
> SELECT "id", "group", "date" FROM cTE ORDER BY maxdategroup DESC,"group" ,  "date" DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | group  | date      
> -: | :----- | :---------
>  5 | group3 | 2012-01-01
>  4 | group3 | 2011-05-05
>  7 | group4 | 2012-01-01
>  6 | group4 | 2011-05-05
>  1 | group1 | 2011-11-24
>  3 | group1 | 2011-03-11
>  2 | group2 | 2011-08-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cdbf2063bd2ed4032bca5c3d295c3ee2)*

Answer (score 6):

Another option, using a window function:

```
select 
    id, "group", date
from 
    table1
order by
    max(date) over (partition by "group") desc,
    "group", 
    date desc ;
```

Thnx to @nbk for providing the [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3615bb0eaab73365be1b85d329526f25)